# SVG components raise a warning

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg

I migrated my application to React 16 and updated some packages in the same time. Now when I run it, I get the warnings:

```
Warning: The tag <g> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
Warning: <foreignObject /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.
Warning: The tag <foreignObject> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
```

I use SVG components to render d3 objects. I am using Chrome 62. These warnings do not seem to be justified by any bug in the application. Does someone have an explanation ?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

Add outer <svg> tags around them:

```
<svg>
  <g />
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there any other way other than this to make the warning go away?  While it works, it needlessly pollutes the DOM tree.